# How to change leading width in ListTile?

Tags: flutter

When using ListTile there are gaps on left and right sides on leading property. Is it possible to reduce them?

[image]

```
child: ListTile(
        leading: GestureDetector(
            onTap: _onPressed,
            child: Container(
                    width: 48,
                    height: 48,
                    color: Colors.amberAccent,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.label_outline,
                      size: 32,
                    ),
                  )
```

Comment: There is no widget available, where it can help you, create custom one

Comment: You can try by this ```ListTile``` inside Column with children ```Container```

Answer (score 2):

You can play with the following attributes:

```
ListTile(
    dense: true,
    minLeadingWidth: X,
    horizontalTitleGap: Y,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(Z),
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy `ListTile` and make a custom one. To change the padding or width of the leading, there are 2 variables you might want to change: `_minLeadingWidth` and `_horizontalTitleGap`